# resize the first column of table i.e number showing column in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I include sample code of my application

1st class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class setcolwidth {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        final Object rowData[][] = {
            {"kirti", "one", "I"},
            {"kkk", "two", "II"},
            {"kiki", "three", "III"}};
        final String columnNames[] = {"#", "English", "Roman"};

        final JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        JXTable lineTable = new LineNumberTable(table);
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(lineTable);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Resizing Table");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        TableColumn column = null;
        int i=0;
        try{

            column = lineTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

                column.setPreferredWidth(50);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error for the column index"+i+" Err"+ex.toString());
        }

        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    }
```

and 2nd class

```
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable;

public class LineNumberTable extends JXTable {
    private JTable mainTable;

    public LineNumberTable(JTable table) {
        super();
        mainTable = table;
        setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel( false );
        setModel( mainTable.getModel() );
        setAutoscrolls( false );
        addColumn( new TableColumn() );
        getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(mainTable.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer());
      //  mainTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(40);
        setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(getPreferredSize());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
         return Integer.valueOf(row+1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowHeight(int row) {
        return mainTable.getRowHeight();
    }
}
```

But the row number column is not resizing.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are setting the preferred size on the column and need to be setting it on the `JViewport` on the row header instead.

After this line:

```
    scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(lineTable);
```

Try this:

```
    scrollPane.getRowHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
```

Comment: You should not manually set the preferred size of the row header. This can lead to scrolling problems. At least I've seen problems when people attempt to set the preferred size of the column header. Setting the preferred width of the column and the preferred scrollable viewport size should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use JXTable so I can't text your code. But your basic logic looks ok to me for a JTable.

Take a look at my [Row Number Table](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/) which works for me. Maybe the difference is the way I create the TableColumn and assign a header value.

Comment: i try Row Number Table as well but i wanna resize the line no component http://nsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/myapp.bmp?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINHDRCMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1303988207&Signature=rzGAOiOW4DYhltRxsSozj%2BbGAMg%3D this image display to you the table i wanna resize column which contain number listing.

Comment: @user609621, When I use a JTable and a RowNumberTable I don't see the white space found in your image. Create a SSCCE (http://sscce.org) using a JTable and the RowNumberTable that demonstrates the problem. Then maybe we can determine if the problem is in your code or in the way JXTable works.